# "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" without code using phpMyAdmin on CentOS7

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, centos, centos7

I'm setting up a new CentOS 7 server with Apache, MySQL and phpMyAdmin.
The installation of MySQL and phpMyAdmin worked as expected. 
For the installations, I used the following guides by Digital Ocean:

[MySQL installation guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7)

[phpMyAdmin installation guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-apache-on-a-centos-7-server)

Loging into MySQL on the server works as expected. 
However, when I try to log into phpMyAdmin, I only get the "cannot log in to the MySQL server" error, but without a code.

This is a fresh installation of everything, so I am unsure what is causing this problem, since I followed all guides to a t.

Comment: When you run this in terminal it should ask password. `mysqladmin -u root -p version` is this working? If you get the password correct it should return the mysql version. You need to use the username root and that password you entered in the phpmyadmin login page

Comment: Doing this works as expected and returns version 8.0.13. However, it only works when using the root account. I don't know if that is the expected behavior.

Comment: If you have other users i think it should work. Anyways this confirms you know the root password and mysql server is working. Now we need to check that your ip address match the one to put while following the guide. It could be that you typed the wrong ip or your ip has changed. Open /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf and check if you ip addresses match if not. Make a copy of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` then open original and comment out the `RequireAny` section and change `Deny from All` to `Allow from All` then try again.

Comment: Also don't forget to restart after make them changes. `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`

Comment: I've already set the phpMyAdmin.conf to Allow from All, without effect. I read somewhere else Require all granted would also work, but still no luck.

I restarted after every change.

Comment: After chaning my password, I'm also able to perform the `mysqladmin -u user -p version` command with my non-root account. Still no luck. 

I also think it has nothing to do with the IP addresses in the conf file, since you get a 'permission denied' message if your IP is not allowed. That's not the case, since I get the default phpMyAdmin login page, only logging in is not functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user [xdk](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/users/xdk) over on the [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-without-code-using-phpmyadmin-on-centos7?answer=47996) community forums.
They said the following:

> Assuming MySQL 8.
>   `ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'PASSWORD';` 
>   Reason: 
>   Some applications are having trouble with `caching _sha2 _password method`. 
>   Above sets the credentials to use the native one.

Executing this did the trick.